# What will be the equivalent resistance in this situation?

Tags: resistors, resistance

[image]

We have to find the equivalent resistance between A and B.

**My attempt:**

Let's simplify the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP7r1cm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now,

$$\frac{1}{R_P}=\frac{1}{5+5}+\frac{1}{5+5}+\frac{1}{5}$$

$$R_P=\frac{5}{2}\Omega$$

However, this is not the correct answer; the correct answer is 3.125 ohm. Why is that?

**Edit:**

I was able to simplify the circuit correctly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOQV7ym.png)</sup>

Comment: You simplified the circuit incorrectly : try again.

Comment: You've redrawn it differently. Try numbering the nodes if  you're having trouble.

Comment: Is R2 really connected to B as you've drawn it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is a good example of why diagonal schematic symbols/connections can make it more difficult to interpret schematics correctly. Re-drawing the circuit without the diagonals should make things more clear:

[image: Original circuit (re-drawn)]

Steps given here for solving:
[image: steps for solving circuit]